# How to add additional url parameters?

Tags: uri, navigation, 7

I would like to know how I can include additional URL parameters to a given link? ie: 'news?pid=3'

```
<?php
print $path='news?pid=3';
?>
```

This returns page not found error as the '?' is getting printed as %3F.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are using `l()`, you would do something like this to create news?pid=3.

```
l('Link Text', 'news', array('query' => array('pid' => '3')));
```

If you have other query parameters, you can add them in like this:

```
l('Link Text', 'news', array('query' => array('pid' => '3', 'foo' => 'bar')));
```

and that would create `news?pid=3&foo=bar`.

More information on `l()` [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7) and `url()` [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/url/7).