# How to use url() correctly?

Tags: uri

I'm trying to generate a custom token to a prepopulated URL.  My code looks like this:

```
        $replacements[$original] = url('user/login', array(
          'query' => array('edit[name]', $account->mail),
          'absolute' => TRUE,
        );
```

The resulting URL looks like this:

http://example.com/en/user/login&edit[name]=myemail@example.com

But the `&` should be a `?` because it's the start of a query string.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is a same issue [How to add additional url parameters?][1].


  [1]: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/38663/how-to-add-additional-url-parameters

Comment: As side note, there is a missing parenthesis.

Comment: It is not the same issue: Patrick knows how to use `url()` but he is getting the wrong result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
    $replacements[$original] = url('user/login', array(
      'query' => array('edit' => array('name' => $account->mail)),
      'absolute' => TRUE,
    ));
```

Sidenote: you are naming the argument as `name` but you are passing the mail.

Comment: Basing on the [`drupal_http_build_query()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_http_build_query/7) code (called from `url()`), this is the correct answer. I don't see what confuses `url()`, which is using `$path .= (strpos($path, '?') !== FALSE ? '&' : '?') . drupal_http_build_query($options ['query']);`, but this is the correct code.

Comment: I tried on a test server, and I got http://test.local/user/login?edit%5Bname%5D=kiamlaluno with the code used by the OP, while I got http://test.local/user/login?edit[name]=kiamlaluno with yours. No _?_ got replaced by _&_.

Comment: @Topsitemakers Thanks, this fixed the issue.  I'm passing an email address for `name` because my site allows users to log in with their email addresses.

Comment: Sure, glad it helped :)